# Programmatically, how can I specify the database in which I want to put my table C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I just wanted to know: Using C#, how can I specify in which database a want to put my table? 
Here is what I am doing:

```
 str2 = "CREATE TABLE maTable4" +
            "(" +
            "Prenom DECIMAL(3)," 
            "Nom varchar(20)," +
            "Famille varchar(20)," +
            ");";
            SqlCommand maCommande = new SqlCommand(str2, myConn);
            try
            {
                myConn.Open();
                maCommande.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConn.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                myConn.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("table created ");
            }
```

As you can see, this table goes no where.

Comment: Doesn't myConn give the database?

Comment: Ads a "USE:    :   "Use DataBase;   Create Table ........."

Comment: yes, myConn give the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a three-segment identifier for your table.
Otherwise, it will be created to the default database you're logged in to, on the login's default schema.

```
str2 = "CREATE TABLE DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName" + // rest of the code...
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you may use one trick

Create connection string Dynamically

```
string connetionString = null;
string ServerName="Your server";
string DatabaseName="Your database";
string UserName="UserName";
string Password="Password";

connetionString =String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3}",ServerName,DatabaseName,UserName,Password);

SqlConnection myConn=new SqlConnection(connetionString);
.
.
.
// rest your code...
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's a little bit long but it works too